# Error #3219 NativeProcess in AIR

Tags: apache-flex, macos, actionscript, air, native

I have a program in AIR 2.6 for Windows and Mac Os platform. Use NativeProcess class to execute native apps that i have included in the project.

In Windows all work fine, but in Mac dont work.

The code is:

```
var executable:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('bin/mac/convert') 
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = executable;
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = params;
nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = workingDirectory;

if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
    start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

The error is in start(...) line:

```
Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'launch path not accesible'.
```

Executable var is a File with path in debug=/Users/awakening/Documents/workspace/flashbuilder/SDTDV/bin-debug/bin/mac/convert

It says that exists=True. Same problem with release build.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get this error if the file you are attempting to execute doesn't have the execute bit set.

You can either use `chmod` at the command line

Or if using Flex/Flash Builder, you can right click on the file and choose properties. Then set the execute bit

[image: Execute Bit]

Comment: Do you set the execute bit on all rows?

Comment: The other rows only come in to play with multi-user systems (e.g. Unix/Linux Servers). Assuming that you're the only user on the system which is developing the app, setting this on `Owner` is all that is really required.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean jar file? To run a JAR file I think you need to make JAVA the executable and pass it the argument of the jar file.

Comment: BTW, I think you can also call /usr/bin/open and pass the JAR file as an argument. That uses the same process as Mac's "Finder" application.

Comment: It isnt a jar file. It is a command line program. In AIR you are indicating the executable file (/Users/awakening/Documents/workspace/flashbuilder/SDTDV/bin-debug/bin/mac/convert), and its arguments.

Comment: Okay, did you try running /usr/bin/open with /Users/awakening/Documents/workspace/flashbuilder/SDTDV/bin-debug/bin/mac/convert as an argument, followed by its arguments?